# use stored JSON instead of Core Data

Tags: android, ios, json, core-data

There are lots of tutorials out there describing how to fetch JSON objects from the web and map them to Core Data.

I'm currently working on an iOS (later: Android as well) app which loads json objects from web and displays them to the user. In my opinion all this mapping from and to Core Data is an overhead in this case, it would be much easier to save the JSON objects directly and use them as "cache" in the app. Are there libraries/documented ways how to achieve fetching json objects, save them locally and fetch them with a predefined identifier?

I would love to fetch e.g. 10 objects, show them to the user and save the data locally. The next time the user is on that list the local data is shown and in the background the json-file is fetched again to be up-to-date. I guess this is a common use case but I didn't find any tutorials/frameworks enabling exactly this.

Comment: I know this is not exactly your question, but have a look at https://realm.io/,  it might be a good alternative for you. Really easy to use and cross-platform. And fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use NSURLCache to cache http responses instead saving JSONs 
http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement this. You can implement cache using either file storage or database depending on the complexity as well as quantity of your data. If you're using files, you just need to store JSON response and load it whenever activity/fragment is crated. What I have done sometimes is store the JSON response in the form of string in a file, and then retrieve it on activity/fragment load. Here's an example of reading and writing string files:

**Writing files:**

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = context.openFileOutput("myfilename",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String stringToBeSaved = myJSONObject.toString();
        outputStream.write(stringToBeSaved.getBytes());
```

**Reading from files**

```
 FileInputStream inputStream= context.openFileInput("myfilename");
        int c;
        String temp="";
        while( (c = inputStream.read()) != -1){
            temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
```

You can convert this string to JSONObject using :

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(temp);
```

Or you can use the string according to your needs.